# Can I add my own snippets to MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

Is there any means within MonoDevelop to create your own snippets, i.e. reusable bits of code? I know in the toolbox you can get other people's, but I can't seem to find a way to add my own stuff into that. Granted, I'm new enough to Monodevelop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MonoDevelop, Go to Tools --> Preferences ---> Text Editor --> Code Templates --> Press the button Add

(In Windows (monodevelop 5.9.6) its Tools --> Options)

Comment: I was going to edit this answer, as on my Mono, the top level menu item is 'Edit', not 'Tools', however I am running the Linux version of  Mono. Could someone please check the Windows version to see where it is, and edit the answer to show either both, or the correct one

Answer (score 0):

[Linux Mint (cinamon 19.1)

In MonoDevelop 7.xx, Go to Tools --> Preferences ---> Text Editor --> Code Snippets --> Press the button Add: set this way:

[image: set up tor add snippents on MonoDevelo 7.xx]